# Finding number of quadruples in an array whose XOR is 0

Tags: combinatorics

If an array of n elements is given and I need to find the number of quadruples whose XOR = 0. I need to do this in very efficient way. Please help.

Comment: Please include details as to the sorts of things you have tried and/or your background in this area. It helps us help you.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're talking about (unordered) sets of four distinct indices in an array $A_n$, $n=1..N$, where each $A_n$ is  a member of $\{0,1\}^d$ (equivalently, an unsigned integer of $d$ bits), not necessarily distinct.   Thus you want $A_{n_1} \oplus A_{n_2} \oplus A_{n_3} \oplus A_{n_4} = 0$ with $1 \le n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < n_4 \le N$.

One method is this.  For each $k$ from $1$ to $N$ and $m$ from $0$ to $3$ let
$L(k,m)$ be the set of pairs $(b,v)$ where $b \in \{0,1\}^d$ is attainable as the XOR of $m$ elements $A_i$, $i \le k$, and $v$ is the number of ways to obtain $b$ as such an XOR.  Of course, $L(k,0) = \{(0, 1)\}$, $L(1,1) = \{(A_1, 1)\}$, and $L(1,2) = L(1,3) = \{\}$.  I'll let you figure out how to compute $L(k+1,m)$ from $L(k,m)$, $A_{k+1}$ and $L(k,m-1)$.  Finally, to get the answer you add $b$ each time $(A_{k+1},b)$ appears in $L(k,3)$.

Comment: Nice, but you have $m$ doing double duty in your notation.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.  Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped @ Robert Israel